# Keep View Content above Keyboard Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                commentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.2, green:0.2, blue:0.2, alpha:1).cgColor
                commentView.layer.borderWidth = 2
            }
        }
    }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
            commentView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }
    }
```

I use this code with two Observers to change y-position of content. But is only works on the first time opening Keyboard.
The second time i show my keyboard, the content stays behind the keyboard.

In addition i edit a textView, but thats not important for the problem solving, i think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078129/uitextfield-is-partially-hidden-by-keyboard-when-opened/58078222#58078222

Comment: You can use `IQKeyboardManager` : https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager